# Enable internet in Tizen wearable emulator

Tags: emulation, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-emulator, tizen-web-simulator

How do I configure my Tizen wearble SDK emulator to use my system's internet connection. This artcle explains [Connecting emulator to a network](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.1/org.tizen.gettingstarted/html/dev_env/emulator_network.htm). But I was not sure what port to use in place of "HOST_PORT" and "GUEST_PORT". Kindly help me on this. I am using Windows 7 OS.

Comment: The Internet works out-of-the-box in the emulator, you don't need to setup anything. What exactly are you trying to do and what's it the problem you are facing?

Comment: As ozbek said We don't need any network configuration to access internet. Just add neccessory privilege in config file before you proceed.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to connect from emulator to outside, you don't need any network configuration. The [Connecting emulator to a network](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.1/org.tizen.gettingstarted/html/dev_env/emulator_network.htm) explains how to connect from outside to emulator.